# Albatross binary search tree

Tags: javascript, binary, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I'm pretty stuck on this question that I have to figure out.

You and a friend have set a wager to see who can find the word
"Albatross" in the dictionary the fastest. Write a program to allow you to win the bet. I know that my if statements are wrong but I'm not sure the best way to go about fixing them.

````
function binarySearch(array, word){
let left = 0;
let right = array.length - 1;
if(word < array.indexOf(word) || word > array.indexOf(word)) {
 return false;
}
while (left <= right){
 let middle = Math.floor((left + right)/2)
   if(array.indexOf(word) === word) {
    return middle;
   } else if(array.indexOf(word) < word){
     left = middle + 1;
   } else {
     right = middle - 1;
   }

}
return null;
}```
````

Comment: Does question not specify the format of the dictionary?

Comment: Why are you comparing array.indexOf(word) to the word? Basically that's doing `4 === "Albatross"` and it will never be true. Instead, I think you want to access the value of the array at the position `middle` i.e. `array[middle] === word`, which will get you `"Parrot" === "Albatross"` and so on.